# tcl: sorting list depending on array

Tags: list, tcl

If `List1` is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

And `array1` is:

```
{3 4 5} {12 13} {20 21}
```

How do I convert `list1` according to `array1` by replacing reverse list of each element of `array1`, i.e., producing this 
output:

```
1 2 5 4 3 6 7 8 9 10 11 13 12 14 15 16 17 18 19 21 20 22 23 24 25
```

```
    ^^^^^               ^^^^^                   ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a *sorting* task, this is a *searching* task.

If you assume that the ranges to reverse do not overlap, but are not necessarily present either (i.e., *not* using the fact that they are contiguous numbers), you get something like this:

```
# Iterate over each of the replacement patterns
foreach range $array1 {
    # Iterate over each of the locations where the first element of the current
    # replacement pattern is found
    foreach pos [lsearch -all -exact $list1 [lindex $range 0]] {
        # This will be the index of the *last* element in each subrange
        set pos2 [expr {$pos + [llength $range] - 1}]

        # Do the reversed replacement if the ranges match
        if {[lrange $list1 $pos $pos2] eq $range} {
            set list1 [lreplace $list1 $pos $pos2 {*}[lreverse $range]]
        }
    }
}
```

The result after this will be in the *updated* `list1` variable. Wrapping into a procedure is left as an exercise.